# JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

I am testing controller with rspec and I get this error
Test:
quizes_controller_spec.rb:

```
 require 'rails_helper'
    require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::QuizzesController, :type => :controller do
    before (:each) do
        @instructor = create(:instructor)
    end
describe "instructor_index method" do
        it "returns all quizzes of the current instructor" do
            sign_in @instructor
            @quiz = create(:quiz)
            @instructor.quizzes << @quiz
            get :instructor_index
            quiz_response = json(response.body)
            expect(response.status).to eq(200)
            expect(quiz_response[:success]).to eql(true)
            expect((quiz_response[:data][:quizzes]).first[:name]).to eql(@quiz.name)
        end
    end
end
```

In index method it is rendering the quizzes of the instructor:
quizzes_controller.rb:

```
def instructor_index
            quizzes = current_instructor.quizzes
            render json: { success:true, data:{:quizzes => quizzes},info:{} }, status: 200
        end
```

aftur runnig rspec this error appears :

> Api::QuizzesController instructor_index method returns all quizzes of the current instructor
>        Failure/Error: quiz_response = json(response.body)
>        JSON::ParserError:
>          757: unexpected token at 'You are being [redirected](http://test.host/instructors/sign_in).'
>        # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:9:in `json'
>        # ./spec/controllers/quizzes_controller_spec.rb:60:in`block (3 levels) in '

rails_helper.rb:

```
def json(body)  
  JSON.parse(body, symbolize_names: true) 
end
```

Comment: Would you mind to try to `puts quizzes` right after `quizzes = current_instructor.quizzes` in `instructor_index`? What’s being printed?

Comment: #<Quiz:0x00000003475588>
#<Quiz:0x000000032b7f48>
#<Quiz:0x000000032b5ab8>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 97ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template api/quizzes/instructor_index, application/instructor_index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/fakhreldin-m-abdelkhalik/sQuiz/Ruby-on-Rails-application/sQuiz/app/views"
  * "/home/fakhreldin-m-abdelkhalik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
):
@mudasobwa

Comment: This happens if I removed render json:

Comment: if I just add puts quizzes this appears in the server:  
  Instructor Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "instructors".* FROM "instructors"  WHERE "instructors"."email" = 'fakhr@example.com'  ORDER BY "instructors"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Quiz Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "quizzes".* FROM "quizzes"  WHERE "quizzes"."instructor_id" = ?  [["instructor_id", 6]]
#<Quiz:0x00000004f01550>
#<Quiz:0x00000004f010c8>
#<Quiz:0x00000004f00df8>
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 2.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

Comment: The response in console: {"success":true,"data":{"quizzes":[{"id":1,"name":"fezyaaaa2","subject":"a7ya2","duration":20,"no_of_MCQ":5,"no_of_rearrangeQ":5,"instructor_id":6,"created_at":"2015-01-28T18:33:23.100Z","updated_at":"2015-02-07T23:20:23.838Z"},{"id":2,"name":"eltany","subject":"3kim","duration":20,"no_of_MCQ":5,"no_of_rearrangeQ":5,"instructor_id":6,"created_at":"2015-01-28T18:33:44.233Z","updated_at":"2015-02-06T09:55:23.517Z"} it renders quizzes with no problem.

Comment: Sounds like a filter in your controller is redirecting

Comment: How to solve this then ? @FrederickCheung

Comment: I'd start by finding out which filter is redirecting - your log file should contain that information